# difference between parquet schema and parquet using avro schema

Tags: hive, spark-streaming, avro, parquet

I am new to parquet, can you share what are pros and cons in parquet using Avro schema over parquet using its own schema format in the hive.

Currently, I store files in parquet in HDFS using spark streaming and then create a table in HIVE using `"create table IF NOT EXISTS"`. Does this update schema in the hive? If not, what is the ideal way to update the latest schema in both formats?

Comment: Pls add the code, what you tried.  Have you googled for **parquet vs avro**?

Comment: hi srinivas, i'm going to use parquet also looking to use avro schemas in parquet to handle schema evolution.